# Get Length of agtype List/ Array

Tags: database, postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

I have created this vertex:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
CREATE (s:student{name:"Muneeb", courses: ["OOP", "DS", "Programming", "Android"]})
 RETURN s
$$) as (student agtype);

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     student    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

{"id": 3377699720527873, "label": "student", "properties": {"name": "Muneeb", "courses": ["OOP", "DS", "Programming", "Android"]}}::vertex
    (1 row)
```

I want to get the length of `courses` List. How can I do that.

I tried `ARRAY_LENGTH` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [size](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/scalar_functions.html#size) function.

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
     MATCH (u) 
     RETURN size(u.courses)
$$) as (student agtype);
```

Result

```
 student 
---------
 4
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to taha answer, You can also use jsonb_array_length:
The example code for this

```
 SELECT jsonb_array_length((student.properties ->> 'courses')::jsonb) AS 

    num_courses
    FROM cypher('graph', $$
        MATCH (s:student)
        WHERE s.name = 'Muneeb'
        RETURN s
    $$) AS (student agtype);
```

Th output will be:

```
 num_courses 
-------------
           4
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
     MATCH (s:student)
     WHERE s.name = 'Muneeb'
     RETURN size(s.courses)
$$) as (length agtype);
```

This return the length of courses array for nodes with tag student and name Muneeb.

[Docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/scalar_functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

using the `size` function from the official docs you can get the length of an array

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    WITH ["OOP", "DS", "Programming", "Android"] as courses
    RETURN size(courses) $$) as (size_of_courses agtype);
```

Use the same approach for your scenario like

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
CREATE (s:student{name:"Muneeb", courses: ["OOP", "DS", "Programming", 
 "Android"]})
 RETURN s, size(s.courses)
 $$) as (student agtype, length_of_courses agtype);
```